# Image with text as a resource file

Tags: android, android-layout

My client gave me images with text on them in png to use as buttons in the app.

Is it bad to use them that way or should I ask for images without text and I use the android:text property to write text on it?

I found the image with text in a resource file to be good that text is already position with the right font but I feel it is not good approach

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly not a good approach. Yes, you should use `android:text` to write text. See Android runs on different sized devices, so your button will have a different size in different devices and the text may not be readable in some of them.

But when you use the `text` attribute, your background image may have a bad quality, but the text will still be readable.

Comment: But when using images on different device, it will be in dp so really it will show up as the same size regardless of the screen size. no?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a bad approach, many apps use already generated images this way, so I can't see why this can be a bad way of doing it.